# SVG buttons inside zebra-striped table do not inherit background color

Tags: html, css

In plain HTML5 and CSS, I want to style some buttons within a zebra-striped table. The background colour of the buttons should be the same as the background colour of each cell. I was expecting that the background colour of the buttons would be inherited from the parent `<td>` but apparently not.

Here's my current result, you can see that the button on row 2 should have a white background, not grey:

[image: Zebra-striped table with SVG buttons in column]

The code that generates this is:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                width: 50%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                margin: 3px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            thead {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #000;
            }
            tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
                background: #eee;
            }
            tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
                background: #fff;
            }
            button {
                border: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>id</td>
                    <td>symbol</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>
                        <button>
                            <svg
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                width="24"
                                height="24"
                                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            >
                                <path d="M12 3l12 18h-24z" fill="#3c3c3b" />
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>
                        <button>
                            <svg
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                width="24"
                                height="24"
                                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            >
                                <path d="M12 21l-12-18h24z" fill="#3c3c3b" />
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you can see the same thing in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snim2/Lntojk9w/1/).

What do I need to do to the CSS to make this work?

Comment: Try to use `button {background-color: transparent;}` to remove the default button background.

Comment: Oh brilliant, thanks. Is that compatible with most browsers?

Comment: Yes, it's compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default button background color is what was showing up. You can also style the SVG by removing the fill attribute from the `<path>` elements and adding CSS for it.

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
thead {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
  fill: red;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
  fill: green;
}
button {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>id</td>
                    <td>symbol</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>
                        <button>
                            <svg
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                width="24"
                                height="24"
                                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            >
                                <path d="M12 3l12 18h-24z" />
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>
                        <button>
                            <svg
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                width="24"
                                height="24"
                                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            >
                                <path d="M12 21l-12-18h24z" />
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```